# \captionsetup turn on numbering for new caption

Tags: tables, formatting, captions, center, newfloat

For my thesis, I want to create a new caption that says **Model 1**, **Model 2**, etc.
So far, I've gotten to it saying **Model**, but no numbering yet.

I've used this command:

```
\captionsetup[model]{name=Model, labelformat = original}
```

I want to use it in the following setting:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}
        bla bla bla
    \end{tabular}
      \captionof{model}{caption}\label{Tab:model1}}
\end{center}
```

What do I add in my captionsetup to make sure it does the numbering (correctly)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It works also with `\captionof`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small, labelfont=bf]
            {caption}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Model}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
    table I              \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{A caption II}
    \end{table}

    \begin{center}              %   <---
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
    table               \\
    bla bla bla bla bla \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{A caption II} %   <---
\label{tab:model1}
    \end{center}
See table \ref{tab:model1} ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But this will make all my tables be named model, right? Because some tables I need to mark as model, and some as Table. And I also want that to return in my referencing. Is that possible?

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

With a new environment `model`, you can number and reference the regular tables and the tables of the models separately.

The environment requires 2 parameters: the caption and the table itself, both within braces.

With this approach the models are not a float, they will stay where you put them, which I think is an advantage.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom,
    labelfont={bf, small},
    labelsep=space,
    textfont={small},
    aboveskip=3pt, 
    singlelinecheck=off,
    justification=centering}

% ******************** added
\newcounter{modelnumber}
\newenvironment{model}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{modelnumber}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}    
    #2 \smallskip\par
    \small\textbf{Model~\themodelnumber}\, #1%  
\end{minipage}
}
{\medskip}


\begin{document}        

\begin{model}{A caption for model I\label{Tab:model1}}      
        {\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        model model model 
\end{tabular}}
    \end{model} 

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    normal table
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A caption for table I}\label{Tab:table1}
\end{table} 

\begin{model}{A caption for  model II\label{Tab:model2}}
{\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
    model model model model model
\end{tabular}}
\end{model} 

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    Another normal table
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A caption for  table II}\label{Tab:table2}
\end{table} 

See Table~\ref{Tab:table1} and Table~\ref{Tab:table2}, and also Model~\ref{Tab:model1} and Model~\ref{Tab:model2}   

\end{document}
```

[image: c]

Using the `newfloat` package it is possible to add a new float (`Model`) in addition to the `table` and `figure`. Use `\listofModels` to list the all the models.

[image: d]

[image: e]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{newfloat}% added <<<<

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=fml,placement={!ht},name=Model]{Model} % fmodel as a new float

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom,
    labelfont={bf, small},
    labelsep=space,
    textfont={small},
    aboveskip=3pt, 
    singlelinecheck=off,
    justification=centering}

    \captionsetup[Model]{position=bottom,
    labelfont={bf, small},
    labelsep=space,
    textfont={small},
    aboveskip=3pt, 
    singlelinecheck=off,
    justification=centering}
    
\newenvironment{model} % added <<<<<<<<<<
{\begin{Model}[tb]          
}% send to top or bottom by using [tb]
{\end{Model}}

\begin{document}    
    \listoftables
    \listofModels  % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage
                    
    \lipsum[2]  

\begin{model}   
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        model model model model
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{Model}{A caption for model I}\label{Tab:model1}
\end{model} 

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        normal table
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A caption for table I}\label{Tab:table1}
\end{table} 

\begin{model}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        model model model model model
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{Model}{A caption for model II}\label{Tab:model2}
\end{model} 

\begin{table}[ht!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            Another normal table
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{A caption for  table II}\label{Tab:table2}
\end{table} 

See Table~\ref{Tab:table1} and Table~\ref{Tab:table2}, and also Model~\ref{Tab:model1} and Model~\ref{Tab:model2}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But this will make all my tables be named model, right? Because some tables I need to mark as model, and some as Table. And I also want that to return in my referencing. Is that possible?

Comment: @Britta See the updated answer.